# Understanding a proof of the Pasting Lemma

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> **Pasting Lemma.** Let $A$ and $B$ be both open or closed subsets of a topological space $X$ such that $A \cup B = X$. Let $f: A \to Y$ and $g: B \to Y$ be continuous such that $f = g$ for all $x \in A \cap B$. Prove that $h: X \to Y$ is continuous such that $h\restriction_A = f$ and $h\restriction_B = g$.
>
> Proof: Assume $A$ and $B$ are both closed. Take a subset $C \subset Y$ to be closed. We must prove that $h^{-1}(C)$ is closed, and then we are done. (cont'd)

**Question 1**: Why does it suffice to prove that $h^{-1}(C)$ is closed? Don't we also have to prove that $h\restriction_A = f$ and $h\restriction_B = g$? It says in the problem to prove two things: that $h: X \to Y$ is continuous and that $h\restriction_A = f$ and $h\restriction_B = g$. I understand that if we prove that $h^{-1}(C)$ is closed, then we have successfully proved the continuity of $h: X \to Y$. But it doesn't address the second statement f the proof that $h\restriction_A = f$ and $h\restriction_B = g$.

> Proof (cont'd): We know that $h^{-1}(C) = f^{-1}(C) \cup g^{-1}(C)$. (cont'd)

**Question 2**: How do we know this? There's nothing in our given information that says this. All the information we know is that "*Let $A$ and $B$ be both open or closed subsets of a topological space $X$ such that $A \cup B = X$. Let $f: A \to Y$ and $g: B \to Y$ be continuous such that $f = g$ for all $x \in A \cap B$.*" How can we construct $h^{-1}(C) = f^{-1}(C) \cup g^{-1}(C)$ from just this information?

> Proof (cont'd): *(Omitted because I understand the rest of the proof)*

**Question 3**: Can $A$ and $B$ both be clopen? Or can $A$ and $B$ be disjoint subsets of $X$?

Comment: As this proof appears to come from some external source, you should [edit] your question to indicate where it is from. For example, if it is from a text include the name(s) of the author(s), the title, and where in the book it is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $h$ is *defined* by $h\restriction_A=f$ and $h\restriction_B=g$. There's a unique function with those properties: since $X=A\cup B$, an element $x\in X$ either is in $A$ or in $B$; in the former case define $h(x)=f(x)$, in the latter define $h(x)=g(x)$. This is a good definition, because $f(x)=g(x)$ if $x\in A\cap B$.

Now a function is continuous if and only if the inverse image of closed sets is closed.

Let $x\in h^{-1}(C)$; then either $x\in A$ or $x\in B$; in the former case $h(x)=f(x)$, so $x\in f^{-1}(C)$, in the latter $x\in g^{-1}(C)$. Therefore $h^{-1}(C)\subseteq f^{-1}(C)\cup g^{-1}(C)$. Can you prove the converse inclusion?

Finally there's nothing in the question that suggests $A$ and $B$ be clopen or disjoint.

Comment: I have a question about logical quantifiers then...in general, if a question says "prove that if A, then B such that C" can we assume both $A$ and $C$ and just prove $B$? Because for this proof, I thought we had to prove that $h \restriction A=f$ and $h \restriction B=g$, as it states in the problem.

Comment: @morphic Indeed, I agree that the statement of the problem is unclear. I'd prefer “prove that the unique function $h\colon X\to Y$ such that $h\restriction_A=f$ and $h\restriction_B=g$ is continuous”.

Comment: Also since the question says "Let $A$ and $B$ be both open or closed subsets of a topological space $X$ such that $A \cup B=X$" I don't see anything preventing $A$ and $B$ being both open and closed because the "or" in the statement is ambiguous (is it either or, or can it be both?) and it says $A \cup B=X$ but $A$ and $B$ can still be disjoint unions such that $A \cup B=X$, can't it?

Comment: @morphic There are *two* problems: one for the case in which $A$ and $B$ are closed, one for the case in which they're open. Of course these include the case in which they're both clopen, but it's irrelevant, isn't it?